# Nested masking of asynchronous exceptions

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, exception

I'm writing a database library of sorts. The basic function it exports is the following:

```
withDatabase :: FilePath -> (DBHandle -> IO a) -> IO a
```

which automatically manages the lifetime of database handles.

Internally, `withDatabase` uses the `bracket` function from *Control.Exception*.

```
withDatabase path f = bracket (openDatabase path) closeDatabase f
```

In my specific case, `openDatabase` may perform some significant I/O and thus block for a long time. For this reason, I would like to run some part of it with asynchronous exceptions unmasked. A (simplified) implementation could be:

```
openDatabase :: FilePath -> IO DBHandle
openDatabase path = mask $ \restore -> do
                      h <- openFile path ReadWriteMode
                      restore (doLongStuff h) `onException` (hClose h)
                      ...
                      return (DBHandle h)
```

I'm not sure this code is producing the effect I intend.

Let's look back at `withDatabase`, this time replacing `bracket` with its definition:

```
withDatabase path f = mask $ \restore -> do
  h <- openDatabase path
  r <- restore (f h) `onException` closeDatabase h
  _ <- closeDatabase h
  return r
```

At a certain point in the execution, the call stack becomes the following:

```
\- withDatabase
 \- mask
  \- openDatabase
   \- mask
    \- restore
     \- doLongStuff
```

The documentation for the *Control.Exception* module has something about nested calls to `mask`:

> Note that the restore action passed to the argument to mask does not necessarily unmask asynchronous exceptions, it just restores the masking state to that of the enclosing context. Thus if asynchronous exceptions are already masked, mask cannot be used to unmask exceptions again.

My understanding of this description is that `doLongStuff` will work with asynchronous exceptions masked and not, as I would like, unblocked.

In my real code, I cannot move neither `openFile` nor `doLongStuff` out of `openDatabase`: in fact, `openDatabase` may open any number of files and/or perform various I/Os before "deciding" which handle it wants to return to `withDatabase`. Given this contraint, is there any way to make `doLongStuff` interruptible even if it happens to run inside a nested `mask` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `doLongStuff` being done on the database?  If so, it may already be interruptible.  See the section on [Interruptible Operations](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#g:14), which states that any function which may block, including most functions that perform IO, can be interrupted even within the scope of a mask.

If you're not sure if `doLongStuff` is interruptible or not (depends which functions it uses), then you can either use `allowInterrupt` to poll for async exceptions within masked code, or alternatively use an `MVar` to synchronize reading from the DB.  This would work because most `MVar` operations are interruptible themselves, allowing the larger function to also be interruptible.